# Aiogram message_handler problems

Tags: python, dictionary, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def on_right_word(message: types.Message):
    chat = get_current_chat(message.chat.id)
    if chat['current_word'] == message.text.lower():
        sender = message.from_user
        return await message.reply(text = f'123')
```

This handler triggers only for messages which start with '/'. 'chat' is a dictionary.
But handler must take any text message and doing something, if text is equal to chat['current_word'], but if not is just ignores message. Any ideas?

Comment: Also i have 2 more message handlers. But one is just '/start' handler, and second triggers only for new member in chat

Comment: Perhaps changing ur handler to `@dp.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)`?

Comment: Got Exception 
NameError: Invalid filter name(s): 'func'